# Google Cloud Platform - Deployment Manager - Cloud Run Service as an API Type Provider

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-deployment-manager

I followed this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dinvlad/fcf72039c403bc2bf46663fb43c62a57) to create an API Type Provider for cloud run service.

**Here is my options.yaml**

```
- name: mydepl-001-provider
  type: deploymentmanager.local.typeProvider
  properties:
    descriptorUrl: https://run.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1alpha1
    options:
      inputMappings:
      - fieldName: Authorization
        location: HEADER
        value: >
          $.concat("Bearer ", $.googleOauth2AccessToken())

    collectionOverrides:
    - collection: projects.locations.services
      methodMap:
        get: run.projects.locations.services.get
        create: run.projects.locations.services.create
        delete: run.projects.locations.services.delete
        update: run.projects.locations.services.replaceService
        setIamPolicy: run.projects.locations.services.setIamPolicy
      options:
        virtualProperties: |
          schema: http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#
          type: object
          properties:
            spec:
              type: object
              description: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1alpha1/RevisionSpec

        inputMappings:
        - fieldName: Authorization
          location: HEADER
          value: >
            $.concat("Bearer ", $.googleOauth2AccessToken())

        - methodMatch: ^create$
          location: PATH
          fieldName: parent
          value: $.concat("projects/spatial-cat-319209/locations/asia-south1")

        - methodMatch: ^(get|replaceService|delete)$
          location: PATH
          fieldName: name
          value: $.concat("projects/spatial-cat-319209/locations/asia-south1/services/", $.resource.name)

        - methodMatch: ^setIamPolicy$
          location: PATH
          fieldName: resource
          value: $.concat("projects/spatial-cat-319209/locations/asia-south1/services/", $.resource.name)

        - methodMatch: ^(create|replaceService)$
          location: BODY
          fieldName: kind
          value: $.concat("Service")

        - methodMatch: ^(create|replaceService)$
          location: BODY
          fieldName: apiVersion
          value: $.concat("serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1")

        - methodMatch: ^create$
          location: BODY
          fieldName: metadata.name
          value: $.resource.name

        - methodMatch: ^replaceService$
          location: BODY
          fieldName: metadata
          value: $.resource.self.metadata

        - methodMatch: ^(create|replaceService)$
          location: BODY
          fieldName: spec.template.spec
          value: $.resource.properties.spec
```

**Here is my tp-cloudrun.py:**

```
"""Creates the Cloud Run endpoint."""


def GenerateConfig(context):
    name: str = context.env['name']
    project = context.env['project']
    region = context.properties['region']

    resources = [{
        'name': name,
        'type': context.env['project'] + '/tp-cloudrun:run.projects.locations.services.create',
        'properties': {
            'parent': 'projects/{}/locations/{}'.format(project, region),
            'apiVersion': 'serving.knative.dev/v1',
            'kind': 'Service',
            'metadata': {
                'name': '{}-blah'.format(name),  # TODO rename
                'namespace': 'spatial-cat-319209',  # TODO change to your value
            },
            'spec': {
                'template': {
                    'spec': {
                        'containerConcurrency': 80,
                        'timeoutSeconds': 300,
                        'serviceAccountName': '123456789-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com',  # TODO change to your value
                        'containers': [{'image': 'us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello@sha256:244fd3d0268aa56777020d0bd1b9c0b828f2f0a8f403dbcd26eba5610a450e2c'}],  # TODO change to your value
                    },
                },
                'traffic': [
                    {'percent': 100, 'latestRevision': True}
                ],
            },
        }
    }]

    return {'resources': resources}
```

**Here is my tp-cloudrun.yaml**

```
imports:
- path: tp-cloudrun.py

resources:
- name: my-service-001
  type: tp-cloudrun.py
  properties:
   region: asia-south1
```

**I create the API type provider using the following command:**

```
gcloud beta deployment-manager type-providers create tp-cloudrun --api-options-file=options.yaml --descriptor-url="https://run.googleapis.com/\$discovery/rest?version=v1"
```

**I check if the provider is available and it is**

```
gcloud beta deployment-manager types list --provider tp-cloudrun
```

I initiate the deployment manager using the following command:

```
gcloud beta deployment-manager deployments create my-deployment-001 --config=tp-cloudrun.yaml
```

Here is the response I get

```
{"ResourceType":"spatial-cat-319209/tp-cloudrun:run.projects.locations.services.create","ResourceErrorCode":"401","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":401,"message":"Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.","status":"UNAUTHENTICATED","statusMessage":"Unauthorized","requestPath":"https://run.googleapis.com/v1/projects/spatial-cat-319209/locations/asia-south1/services","httpMethod":"POST"}}
```

**My question is this**
Despite having provided the options inputMappings for Authorization header with the bearer token - why am I getting this error?

Comment: Deployment Manager is not authorized. Did you set up a service account for Deployment Manager to use? There are several methods 1) Setup **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** 2) gcloud auth application-default login

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just so you know, I am running this from the cloud shell `gcloud auth application-default login

You are running on a Google Compute Engine virtual machine.
The service credentials associated with this virtual machine
will automatically be used by Application Default
Credentials, so it is not necessary to use this command.`

Comment: Deployment Manager is not authorized. Which roles do you have assigned to your identity? Cloud Shell uses your identity for authorization. https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/access-control

Comment: The error means that Deployment Manager has no credentials. From Cloud Shell execute `gcloud auth application-default login`

Comment: The cloud shell executes with my authorization and i am able to deploy other components well without issues. I have also verified that the id has admin access to deployment manager and the cloud run service. I am getting this issue only when I try the API Type Provider which requires Oauth2 authentication .and I am passing that in the options.yaml

Comment: Also I tried what you suggested @John and I dont see any change in behavior. I am being told in other forums that I should start using terraform instead of DM ... just wondering if you have the same advice for me as well?

Comment: I think your problem is with this line `$.concat("Bearer ", $.googleOauth2AccessToken())` The error message means that you have no credentials. Note: A service account is OAuth2. Regarding DM versus Terraform. Both are good products. Personally, I prefer Terraform because I invested the time to master it and I like HashiCorp's style. That is a preference and not a recommendation.

Comment: I tried debugging with the argument --log-http and it does show me that the bearer token is passed (although shows as redacted which makes sense). Can you tell me what you think is wrong with that $.concat line?

Comment: The error message says that there is a problem with authorization

Comment: yes it does. Do you have a working example of a similar setup that I can refer to?

Comment: Deployment Manager does not support Cloud Run yet. You can refer to [APIs for supported resources](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types#apis_for_supported_resources) and [Supported GCP type providers](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-gcp-types) for more information, it is suggested to use [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service) for this purpose instead.

Comment: It's a known issue to google. You can find it in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/118583182). As suggested above use Terraform.